# javascript - 'checkAll' weird behavior when only ONE check box

Tags: javascript

I've got a piece of JavaScript that is supposed to check or UN-check ALL my check boxes (named the same) .. works fine when there is more than one check box... doesn't work if only one check box exists. (I realize that the practical difference between clicking 'check All' on a single option screen is identical, and one could argue that the 'check All' shouldn't even appear on a screen with only ONE option - however the client is insistent on consistent screens...so please don't take me down a route I've already argued)

the script:

```
// check uncheck all check boxes
var checkAll = function( checkname, exby ) { 
    alert( checkname.length ); // undefined when there is only one check box
    for ( i = 0; i < checkname.length; i++ ) {
        checkname[i].checked = exby.checked ? true : false;
    }
}
```

NOTE - I added an alert to check the length, and it is undefined when there is only ONE check box, but is accurate any other time????

the HTML that DOESN'T work...

```
<form method="post" name="createInvoice" >
    Check/Uncheck All <input name="chkAll" onclick="checkAll( document.createInvoice.PO, this );" type="checkbox" >
    <input name="PO" value="7835" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" >
</form>
```

the HTML that DOES...

```
<form method="post" name="createInvoice" >
    Check/Uncheck All <input name="chkAll" onclick="checkAll( document.createInvoice.PO, this );" type="checkbox" >
    <input name="PO" value="13506" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" >
    <input name="PO" value="14046" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" >
</form>
```

Comment: Shameless self promotion (if you're already using, or don't mind introducing, jQuery): http://mjball.github.io/jQuery-CheckAll/

Comment: Shouldn't your checkboxes have different names?

Comment: @j08691 While it is **generally** a good idea to keep names separate, his check-boxes are functioning as a multiselect, so the names being the same makes sense.  You still can't have duplicate IDs though.

Comment: @DMoses - I'm thinking from more of a server side perspective. Since the name isn't an array (e.g. PO[]) how will the data be used? Guess the OP doesn't have any issues since it's not part of the question.

Comment: @j08691 Parameter keys don't need brackets.  It'll be posted as `PO=13506&PO=14046`.  All webservers will give you all the values.  Some scripting languages like php or perl use the bracket syntax as a convenient syntactic sugar, but are not required by any means.

Comment: @DMoses - It's being submitted via post, not get.

Comment: @j08691 `POST` still sends the data as `PO=13506&PO=14046`.  It just uses `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and puts the string in the content body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is only 1 then it is the element, and not an array.

```
if (!!checkname.length) {
    for ( i = 0; i < checkname.length; i++ ) {
        checkname[i].checked = exby.checked ? true : false;
    }
} else {
    checkname.checked = exby.checked ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because thats how it has been implemented.

> Name can be used in the document.getElementsByName() method, a form and with the form elements collection. When used with a form or elements collection, it may return a single element or a collection.

[See Document Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.name)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fL8Pf/)

```
var checkAll = function( checkname, exby ) { 
  if(!checkname.length)
  {
      checkname.checked = exby.checked ? true : false;
      return;
  }
    alert( checkname.length ); // undefined when there is only one check box
    for ( i = 0; i < checkname.length; i++ ) {
        checkname[i].checked = exby.checked ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 reference link.  I feel like people are skipping the references and using SO when the documentation is often more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that when you have one checkbox with the name "PO", then `document.createInvoice.PO` will evaluate to the single DOM element with that name. When there is more than one, apparently it will give you a list of DOM elements, which has a `length` property.

So when there's only one, you aren't getting a length.

You could add logic to handle either case:

```
var checkAll = function( checkbox, exby ) {
    var checkboxes = checkbox.length ? checkbox : [checkbox];
    for ( i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++ ) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = exby.checked;
    }
};
```